# How to call a Rules action settings form via drupal_get_form

Tags: forms, commerce, rules

So, I'm trying to embed the form I find at '/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/commerce_payment_paypal_wps/edit/3' - which contains the settings for the PayPal business, etc (from commerce_paypal_wps.module).

Looking in rules/ui/ui.controller.inc I can see it's called thus:

```
$items[$base_path . '/manage/%rules_config/edit/%rules_element'] = array(
      'title callback' => 'rules_get_title',
      'title arguments' => array('Editing !plugin "!label"', $base_count + 3),
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('rules_ui_edit_element', $base_count + 1, $base_count + 3, $base_path),
      'access arguments' => array('administer rules'),
      'load arguments' => array($base_count + 1),
      'file' => 'ui/ui.forms.inc',
      'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'rules'),
    );
```

I'm not entirely sure what extra things I should be passing into drupal_get_form('rules_ui_edit_element') to make it render the form as it does normally.

How on earth do I get that rules action settings form to render either through drupal_get_form, or some other mechanism, so I can put it at the URL of my choosing, and make it look a bit more presentable to our clients?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This is a rules configuration form, just displaying it won't do much, the action is not executed when that form is submitted but when the corresponding event is executed.

Comment: @Berdir: He doesn't want to invoke an event, but to change the url of the settings form, for an action/event.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using an old version of commerce to get an url like that. It was changed long ago to `dmin/commerce/config/payment-methods/...`

In `hook_menu`, the commerce_payment_ui module creates the path, where the rules forms should be located:

```
// Add the menu items for the various Rules forms.
$controller = new RulesUIController();
$items += $controller->config_menu('admin/commerce/config/payment-methods');
```

You could alter those if you want to change the url. You should however be aware that this url is also used elsewhere:

```
/**
 * Builds the payment settings page using the Rules UI overview table filtered
 *   to display payment method rules.
 */
function commerce_payment_ui_admin_page() {
  RulesPluginUI::$basePath = 'admin/commerce/config/payment-methods';

  ...
}
```

Since most of what Rules does, including creating these settings form is classed based, it wont exactly be easy to create the form. I haven't delved much into the Rules code, but I remember seeing public functions called

- `form`
- `form_validate`
- `form_submit`

I believe these are used to create the form, but how it ends up in the FAPI is beyond me. If all you want is to change the path, you could just use `hook_menu_alter` and for commerce, overwrite the `commerce_payment_ui_admin_page` function with your own to create the overview table.

Comment: Turns out I was going through the Rules UI rather than the Commerce Payment UI, which gave me the old URL structure - we're on the Commerce Beta. I guess the right way to go, then, is to menu_alter the original rule form, and then form_alter it to look better (add our own validation, etc), and make sure form_submit for that rule gets called.